# concat 3 columns in csv,How to do this?

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8

I am trying to create a unique id for the data in the csv file.
I have 3 columns in a csv and want to concat 3 columns in to  1 column and output in 4th column,
How to do this?
example:
col1  col2 col3     col4
ab     cd    ef    ab_cd_ef

this should be done to all the other rows as well,I have like around 90k rows.

Comment: I am using logstash to load data to elastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logstash csv input to import the date to elasticsearch. Following configuration will parse the csv files and sent to elasticsearch with a spesific pipeline.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    type => "myindex"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Ref","ID","Case_Number","Date","Block","IUCR","Primary_Type","Description","Location_Description","Arrest","Domestic","Beat","District","Ward","Community_Area","FBI_Code","X_Coordinate","Y_Coordinate","Year","Updated_On","Latitude","Longitude","Location"]
    remove_field => ["Location"]
  }
}

output {
  stdout
  {

  }

  elasticsearch
  {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "myindex"
    template_name => "myindex"
    template => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/template.json"
    template_overwrite => true
    document_type => "mytype"
    pipeline => "my_pipeline"
  }
}
```

In this example, we can parse the csv files with logstash after that We can create a pipeline to concat the fields. For example, following example will concat the coordiante fields to `location` field.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_pipeline
{
  "description" : "Crimes in Chicago Pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx.Location = ctx.Location.X_Coordinate + ctx.Location.Y_Coordinate"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For complete example, you can check this repo. (https://github.com/hkulekci/es5-devnot).

On the other hand, logstash also handle your concat transformation. To do this, you can use `mutate` filter of logstash. 
You should update your logstash filter configuration like below:

```
filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Ref","ID","Case_Number","Date","Block","IUCR","Primary_Type","Description","Location_Description","Arrest","Domestic","Beat","District","Ward","Community_Area","FBI_Code","X_Coordinate","Y_Coordinate","Year","Updated_On","Latitude","Longitude","Location"]
    remove_field => ["Location"]
  }
  mutate {
    "add_field" => { "your_new_field" => "%{col_1} %{col_2} ..." }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually now i figured that i have to create unique document_id's instead of concatenating.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean exactly. I tried to implement your question.

Comment: any idea how to crete unique doc_id's for each docum.                       nput {
    file {
        path => "/.csv"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
csv {
   separator => ","
   columns => ["a"]
}
ruby { code => "require 'digest/md5';
event.get['@metadata']['computed_id'] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(event['message'])"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts=>"http:"
 index =>"cv"
 document_type => "csv"
  document_id => "%{[@metadata][computed_id]}"
 }   stdout { codec => rubydebug}
}
 but here i'm getting ruby exception.

Comment: Could you update your question for more clear understanding and give sample response (errors) for more information.

Comment: On the other hand, you can do same behaviour with logstash directly instead of pipeline. With mutate filter : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html

Comment: @dharani I update my response without pipeline scenario. Please check this.